# QT zoom actions: 200%, 100%, 50%

Tags: c++, qt

Thsi question is about adding zoom options of : 200%, 100% and 50% to the tools zoom menu.

I have a QT program running in visual studio. I am trying to add to the menu an option to choose 100%, 200% or 50% zoom options. Problem is I am not sure where to read documentations about such functions and I am having a hard time understanding the code below.

As you can see though there is already two options zoom In and zoom Out. and advanced zoom action. all these are in the menu tools tab. under zoom.

Where can I read documentations about such code? Is there a quick trick to adding the zoom options I need ?

```
 QMenu *zoomMenu = new QMenu(tr("Zoom"));

    mZoomInAction = new QAction(tr("Zoom In"), this);
    mZoomInAction->setIcon(QIcon::fromTheme("zoom-in", QIcon(":/media/actions-icons/zoom-in.png")));
    mZoomInAction->setIconVisibleInMenu(true);
    connect(mZoomInAction, SIGNAL(triggered()), this, SLOT(zoomInAct()));
    zoomMenu->addAction(mZoomInAction);

    mZoomOutAction = new QAction(tr("Zoom Out"), this);
    mZoomOutAction->setIcon(QIcon::fromTheme("zoom-out", QIcon(":/media/actions-icons/zoom-out.png")));
    mZoomOutAction->setIconVisibleInMenu(true);
    connect(mZoomOutAction, SIGNAL(triggered()), this, SLOT(zoomOutAct()));
    zoomMenu->addAction(mZoomOutAction);

    mZoomInAction = new QAction(tr("100%"), this);  //My code for 100% zoom. How to start ?

    QAction *advancedZoomAction = new QAction(tr("Advanced Zoom..."), this);
    advancedZoomAction->setIconVisibleInMenu(true);
    connect(advancedZoomAction, SIGNAL(triggered()), this, SLOT(advancedZoomAct()));
    zoomMenu->addAction(advancedZoomAction);


    mToolsMenu->addMenu(zoomMenu);
```

Comment: "Where can I read documentations about such code?" Which calls?  You need to be more specific.

Comment: I can't even figure out if this is a question about zooming or about menu's.

Comment: I think the title and my question makes it clear what my question is about. But dont worry I edited saying word by word what this question is about. on a spoon

Comment: @cmannett85 I am looking for zooming call of 200%, 100% etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
mZoomIn50Action = new QAction(tr("50%"), this);
connect(mZoomIn50Action, &QAction::triggered, [this](){ zoom(50); });
zoomMenu->addAction(mZoomIn50Action );

mZoomIn100Action = new QAction(tr("100%"), this);
connect(mZoomIn100Action , &QAction::triggered, [this](){ zoom(100); });
zoomMenu->addAction(mZoomIn100Action);

mZoomIn200Action = new QAction(tr("200%"), this);
connect(mZoomIn200Action, &QAction::triggered, [this](){ zoom(200); });
zoomMenu->addAction(mZoomIn200Action);
```

Implement a `zoom( uint percentage )` in your `this` class.

Comment: void MainWindow::zoom50()
{
 getCurrentImageArea()->zoomImage(0.5);
 getCurrentImageArea()->setZoomFactor(0.5);
}
Now this is shrinking it to 0.5 everytime i click 50%. can you help me make it set to 50 % by editing it ?

Comment: @matrixCode that's a completely different question, SO isn't a forum, post it as a new question. If my answer solved your original question, then please accept it.